# Grouping array of element based on their value relation ship in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, npm

I want to group the array elements with their inner array group met

Input:

```js
const arr = [
  [123, 243],
  [123, 435],
  [736, 987],
  [987, 774],
  [123, 666],
  [774, 999],
  [098, 980],
];
```

Output:

```
Result = [[123, 243, 435, 666],[736, 987, 774, 999],[098, 980]]
```

now you can find what i expect ?

I have tried this script but cant complete

```js
function checkVal(array, value) {
  return array.map(function (entry, inx, arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(entry)) {
      return checkVal(entry, value);
    }
    if (entry === value) {
      return arr;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
}
function multiDimensionalUnique(arr) {
  var uniques = [];
  var itemsFound = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    var stringified = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
    if (itemsFound[stringified]) {
      continue;
    }
    uniques.push(arr[i]);
    itemsFound[stringified] = true;
  }
  return uniques;
}
const arr = [
  [123, 243],
  [123, 435],
  [736, 987],
  [987, 774],
  [123, 666],
  [774, 999],
  [098, 980],
];
let firstTake = [];
// Expected Result = [[123, 243, 435, 666],[736, 987, 774, 999],[098, 980]]
let sTake = [];
let i = 0;
arr.forEach((innerArr) => {
  if (i == 0) firstTake.push(innerArr);
  innerArr.forEach((detailArr) => {
    let innerLoopArr = checkVal(arr, detailArr);
    innerLoopArr.forEach((innerLoopArrVal) => {
      var filtered = innerLoopArrVal.filter(el => el != null);
      sTake.push(filtered);
    });
  });
  i++;
});
let clearnArray = sTake.filter(v => v.length != 0);
console.log(multiDimensionalUnique(clearnArray));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce them into array of objects and then check if some of the element in a tuple is in the reduce accumulator. Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but this should do:

```js
const arr = [
  [123, 243],
  [123, 435],
  [736, 987],
  [987, 774],
  [123, 666],
  [774, 999],
  [098, 980],
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let newAcc = acc;

  const currObj = {
    [curr[0]]: null,
    [curr[1]]: null,
  }
  
  for ([index, value] of newAcc.entries()) {
    if (curr.some(c => c in value)) {
    
      newAcc[index] = {
        ...value,
        ...currObj
      }
      
      return newAcc
    }
  }

  newAcc.push(currObj)
  
  return newAcc
}, []).map(obj => Object.keys(obj))

console.log(result)
```

Note that you may notice that the `098` becomes `98`, this is not because of my code, but because in your original array `098` is detected as number, thus javascript converts it to a valid number (`98`). If you want to keep it as `098`, you should make it array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the array is a list of edges of a graph, and you're trying to get a list of sets of nodes in each disjoint graph.

This gets you the result you want:

```
arr.reduce((result, [a, b]) => {
    let g = result.find(g => g.has(a) || g.has(b));
    if (!g) result.push(g = new Set());
    g.add(a).add(b);
    return result;
}, []);
```

(If you want arrays at the end instead of Sets, you can add `.map(s => Array.from(s))` to the end.)

But if you were to add another entry to the array like [736, 666], I'd think the first two sets should be merged. This handles that:

```
const result = arr.reduce((result, [a, b]) => {
    // Get all sets of nodes that contain either node
    let [g, ...gs] = [...result].filter(g => g.has(a) || g.has(b));
    // If none, make a new one
    if (!g) result.add(g = new Set());
    // Add both nodes to the set
    g.add(a).add(b);
    // Merge sets if there's more than one
    for (const h of gs) {
        for (const e of h) g.add(e);
        result.delete(h);
    }
    return result;
}, new Set());
console.log(Array.from(result, s => Array.from(s)));
```